# Наращение числительного 51

Tags: числительные, наращение

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если мне нужно написать "пятьдесят одна" цифрами, то надо будет написать "51-на"?
Выглядит странно, можно ли так делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пятьдесят одна (51) – количественное числительное.
Пятьдесят первая (51-я) – порядковое.

> Наращение не используется:
>
> - В записи количественных числительных: *словарь в 4 томах; работа 2 сотрудников; серия из 12 упражнений.*

См.: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87).

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо! Хорошо, что решил спросить.